# How do I change the directory path of my program whilst its running

Tags: database, vb.net

```
  Private Sub _2013results_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    dBprovider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =" 'This is the type of connection I've chose to link to the database
    'Change the following to your access database location
    datafile = "C:\Year 13\SheetFormats.accdb"
    connString = dBprovider & datafile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
End Sub
```

Specifically on the "datafile" line where it has the path of the data base file
This is meant to be sent to other students and they probably won't have the same path as me so is there any way to create an alert that allows the user to modify the code to fit their path

Comment: That's great.  What is your question?

Comment: How do i allow users to change code whilst running the program

Comment: What are you sending the other students? An executable program? Or code to compile into an executable program? If you are supplying them with code, then they can go into the code and change it. Otherwise, you may want to look into config files to host that information and let the user know where to change what. Or prompt the user and modify the file on their behalf.

Comment: blaze - I'll be sending an executable program not the code. How would i go ahead with prompting the user?

Comment: It's a bit hard to say without seeing the context of your application, but if you want to keep it as simple as possible, until you get more comfortable with code, then I suggest you have a textbox in which the user could supply the path to the db file and then you do something like `datafile = YourDbPathField.value`. What kind of application are you making? Winform, WPF, a website perhaps?

Comment: Have a look at [Interaction.InputBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.inputbox(v=vs.110).aspx). Best of luck.

Comment: Its a winform, the basic concept of the application is that you enter a name from the database and it pulls up the sport results of that student.
If you would like i can display the whole code if that would help you explain it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this can help you get you where you want to go. Once you're comfortable with this code, look into swapping `Private dbFilePath As String` in favor of a [User Setting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwc80dzb.aspx) so that the change can be persisted every time the user uses the application.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private dbFilePath As String = "" 'this is where I will store the path to the DB file

    Private Sub btn_Go_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Go.Click
        If dbFilePath = "" Then
            'if the DB path is empty, the user must provide one
            GetDbFilePath()
            btn_Go_Click(sender, e)
        Else
            'there is already a path
            _2013results_Load("", EventArgs.Empty)
            'on your TO DO list, implement code so that if the user already specified a path but he/she wants to update it.
        End If
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' This sub will 'prompt' the user for a path
    ''' </summary>
    Private Sub GetDbFilePath()
        Dim message, title, defaultValue As String
        Dim myvalue As Object
        message = "Please enter the path of your db file"
        title = "DB path grabber"
        defaultValue = ""
        myvalue = InputBox(message, title, defaultValue)
        If myvalue IsNot "" AndAlso File.Exists(myvalue) Then
            'if the user entered something, and that something is a valid path
            dbFilePath = myvalue
        End If

    End Sub


    Private Sub _2013results_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If dbFilePath = "" Then
            Return
        End If
        Dim dBprovider As String
        dBprovider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =" 'This is the type of connection I've chose to link to the database
        'Change the following to your access database location
        Dim connString = dBprovider & dbFilePath
        Dim myconnection As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection()
        myconnection.ConnectionString = connString
    End Sub


End Class
```

Meh... here it is using user settings. It's a very basic implementation but it gets the job done for little to no requirements. This way assumes you have a user setting called "settings_DbFilePath". To create such setting...

In Solution Explorer -> Your Solution -> Your Project -> Settings

Name: settings_DbFilePath
Type: String
Scope: User
Value:

```
Private Sub GetDbFilePath_UserSettingsWay()
    Dim message, title, defaultValue As String
    Dim myvalue As Object
    message = "Please enter the path of your db file"
    title = "DB path grabber"
    defaultValue = ""
    myvalue = InputBox(message, title, defaultValue)
    If myvalue IsNot "" AndAlso File.Exists(myvalue) Then
        'if the user entered something, and that something is a valid path
        My.MySettings.Default.settings_DbFilePath = myvalue
        My.MySettings.Default.Save()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub _2013results_Load_UserSettingsWay(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If My.MySettings.Default.settings_DbFilePath = "" Then
        Return
    End If
    Dim dBprovider As String
    dBprovider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =" 'This is the type of connection I've chose to link to the database
    'Change the following to your access database location
    Dim connString = dBprovider & My.MySettings.Default.settings_DbFilePath
    Dim myconnection As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection()
    myconnection.ConnectionString = connString
End Sub
```

Here is a third alternative so you can better understand what the other 2 ways are doing, so can pinpoint, where in your code should you implement the methods. In this snippet I basically just refactored and appended some stuff to your existing `_2013results_Load` method. Though, this third alternative does expect you to have created a user setting called `settings_DbFilePath` of type `string`, like described in option #2.

```
Private Sub _2013results_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dBprovider As String
    dBprovider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =" 'This is the type of connection I've chose to link to the database

    'Now lets ask the user for the DB path
    Dim message, title, defaultValue As String 'initialize some strings
    Dim userAnswer As Object 'initialize an object
    message = "Please enter the path of your db file"
    title = "DB path grabber"
    defaultValue = ""
    userAnswer = InputBox(message, title, defaultValue) 'This line triggers the prompt
    If userAnswer IsNot "" AndAlso File.Exists(userAnswer) Then
        'if the user entered something, and that something is a valid path
        My.MySettings.Default.settings_DbFilePath = userAnswer 'park that value in the user setting
        My.MySettings.Default.Save() 'save the settings
    Else
        Return 'the user did not provide a valid path so get out of here without even attempting to connect!
    End If

    Dim userAnswerPulledFromSettings As String
    userAnswerPulledFromSettings = My.MySettings.Default.settings_DbFilePath

    Dim connString = dBprovider & userAnswerPulledFromSettings 'put your connection string together
    Dim myconnection As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection() 'initialize your connection object
    myconnection.ConnectionString = connString 'use your connection string
End Sub
```

In a nutshell

```
datafile = "C:\Year 13\SheetFormats.accdb"
```

became

```
'Now lets ask the user for the DB path
Dim message, title, defaultValue As String 'initialize some strings
Dim userAnswer As Object 'initialize an object
message = "Please enter the path of your db file"
title = "DB path grabber"
defaultValue = ""
userAnswer = InputBox(message, title, defaultValue) 'This line triggers the prompt
If userAnswer IsNot "" AndAlso File.Exists(userAnswer) Then
    'if the user entered something, and that something is a valid path
    My.MySettings.Default.settings_DbFilePath = userAnswer 'park that value in the user setting
    My.MySettings.Default.Save() 'save the settings
Else
    Return 'the user did not provide a valid path so get out of here without even attempting to connect!
End If
Dim userAnswerPulledFromSettings As String
userAnswerPulledFromSettings = My.MySettings.Default.settings_DbFilePath
```

Comment: I'm quite confused on where to implement this in my code

Comment: Where you will implement that in your code is really up to you. What you have to remember is that, regardless of where you implement that, your application must know the path of the DB file before you start piecing the connection string together. I'll update my answer, shortly, with a third alternative that may help you better understand what needs to be achieved.

Comment: Third _alternative_ is up.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a config file.  You can generate it when you install the application, then let the user change the path from there if needed.

Comment: As far as user friendliness goes, in my book, prompting the user and doing the work on their behalf based on their answer(s) is always more elegant and less prone to users making mistakes. I think that asking the general public(_aka non-programmers_) to play around in a config file is asking for trouble.

Comment: Good point.  In that case, he could use a file picker to navigate to the location of the file, then throw the path in there for them.  Still seems a super easy way to go.